# Styles not working on all ASP.NET MVC4 Internet application views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I created an ASP.NET MVC4 application following the steps here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials. Everything was working with the default styles. Then I changed the _Layout.cshtml page by deleting whatever I thought was unnecessary and putting in some bootstrap. It works beautifully for the home page the page that displays the list of items (from the database), but the create, edit, delete and display pages (auto-generated) as well as any pages I try so create now aren't being updated with the styles. They can see the layout page because the text is there but they aren't styled. Funny enough though, if I add a button and set the class then it will look like the bootstrap button. I'm not sure what code to include. Any idea what it could be?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body id="body" style="background-color: transparent !important;">
<form id="form1" method="post" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="topbar">
            <div id="appTitle">
                <a href="default.aspx">Online Applications</a>
            </div>
            <div class="roundcont">
                <div class="roundtop">
                    <img src="images/tl.gif" alt="" width="8" height="8" class="corner" style="display: none" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left: 260px; background-color: white;" id="logoScroll">
</body>
```

Comment: Post your _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: I'd guess that you are referencing the style files with a relative path. Since MVC controllers look like folders, the browser ends up looking in the wrong place. Post your layout code (the bit where you load the css)

Comment: The styles are not automatically (magically?) added. Since Bootstrap is a different framework, you need to add (bootstrap) classes to every object on project.

Comment: @KingCronus that sounds like it could be the problem. What is wrong here?

Comment: Maybe the simplest way would be to just add the scripts and css files to the bundles that are already defined. you can find that in App_Start/BundleConfig.cs

Comment: @Bobby5193 I have added them in BundleConfig.cs :(

Comment: The styles in the body aren't there when I inspect the working pages but they are when I run in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

To:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The tilde in ASP.net forms means root directory. I don't think MVC parses it at such so I imagine that is your problem.

Get rid of it and see what happens :-)

Comment: You are both a gentleman and a scholar. I would have never figured this out on my own. I replaced all the "~/" with "/" and its is finally working!