# Bootstrap styles not working on new MVC4 views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I reference the question/answer [styles-not-working-on-all-asp-net-mvc4-internet-application-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347123/styles-not-working-on-all-asp-net-mvc4-internet-application-views)

Which describes the same issue I am having with a brand new project. I have tried adding the link reference without ~/ but nothing is changing... what am I missing?

_Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the browser's dev console to help diagnose why the stylesheet is not loading properly.

Comment: Are you referencing the bootstrap.css correctly? <link href="@Url.Content("~/content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: I've tried a few variations of referencing the bootstrap.css including with and without ~/ and the way you have suggested David with the same effect. I've also looked at the Dev console where the only warning I get is 'event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.' which I don't believe is related.

Comment: @Jansen, I've loaded a working page and non-working page whilst looking at the 'Network' tab in the developers console in Chrome,  all .CSS and .JS files are loading in the same way (200 OK)? Any suggestions what else to look for?